# Comparison Operator & isnumeric() not compatible?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to check if whether input is numeric, If it is, Compare the number to another.

I tried to resolve one issue by removing int() conversion. But that would render x > 0 useless.

Tried searching online, But there's no simple resolve.

```py
print("This program prints the sum of a range of numbers from x to y")
print("For example, if x is 10 and y is 50, the program will print the sum of numbers")
print("from 10 to 50")

x = int(input("Please enter the value of x: "))
y = int(input("Please enter the value of y: "))

if x.isnumeric() and y.isnumeric():
    if x > 0 and y > 0:
        print("Passed")
    else:
        print("failed")
else:
    print("One or more of your inputs are not numeric!")
```

Got 'int' object has no attribute 'isnumeric' as error
or 
'>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a few issues.

1. [str.isnumeric](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric) applies to strings, but you are trying to call it on an integer, hence you get the error `'int' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'` as error
2. If you then don't convert x to `int`, and leave it as `str` and try to do `x > 0 and y > 0`, you are comparing string and integer, which is not possible, as well, hence the error `'>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`

To resolve this, you can read `x` and `y` as a string, and then convert them to int when comparing them to 0 as follows.

```
print("This program prints the sum of a range of numbers from x to y")
print("For example, if x is 10 and y is 50, the program will print the sum of numbers")
print("from 10 to 50")

#Read x and y as strings
x = input("Please enter the value of x: ")
y = input("Please enter the value of y: ")

#Check if they are numeric
if x.isnumeric() and y.isnumeric():
    #Convert them to int to compare them with 0
    if int(x) > 0 and int(y) > 0:
        print("Passed")
    else:
        print("failed")
else:
    print("One or more of your inputs are not numeric!")
```

Then your output will look like

```
This program prints the sum of a range of numbers from x to y
For example, if x is 10 and y is 50, the program will print the sum of numbers
from 10 to 50
Please enter the value of x: 20
Please enter the value of y: 40
Passed

This program prints the sum of a range of numbers from x to y
For example, if x is 10 and y is 50, the program will print the sum of numbers
from 10 to 50
Please enter the value of x: 10
Please enter the value of y: 60
Passed
```

But hold on, what happened here

```
This program prints the sum of a range of numbers from x to y
For example, if x is 10 and y is 50, the program will print the sum of numbers
from 10 to 50
Please enter the value of x: -20
Please enter the value of y: -40
One or more of your inputs are not numeric!
```

Here I will make a note here that this logic won't work for negative integers
as you can see below, `isnumeric` returns False for negative integers

```
In [1]: '-20'.isnumeric()                                                                                                                             
Out[1]: False
```

Hence a much better approach might be is to try to cast the string as an int, and based on that, check if x is a number or not

```
print("This program prints the sum of a range of numbers from x to y")
print("For example, if x is 10 and y is 50, the program will print the sum of numbers")
print("from 10 to 50")

#Read x and y as strings
x = input("Please enter the value of x: ")
y = input("Please enter the value of y: ")

def is_number(s):

    #If we can cast string to int, it is an int, else it is not
    is_number = False
    try:
        int(s)
        is_number = True
    except ValueError:
        pass

    return is_number

#Check if they are numeric
if is_number(x) and is_number(y):
    #Convert them to int to compare them with 0
    if int(x) > 0 and int(y) > 0:
        print("Passed")
    else:
        print("failed")
else:
    print("One or more of your inputs are not numeric!")
```

Now the code will work for negative integers too

```
This program prints the sum of a range of numbers from x to y
For example, if x is 10 and y is 50, the program will print the sum of numbers
from 10 to 50
Please enter the value of x: -20
Please enter the value of y: -40
failed

This program prints the sum of a range of numbers from x to y
For example, if x is 10 and y is 50, the program will print the sum of numbers
from 10 to 50
Please enter the value of x: hey
Please enter the value of y: hi
One or more of your inputs are not numeric!
```